# How to create a script for loop print ps information

Tags: linux, scripting

Just as title mentioned, How can I oversee a process using ps with periodicity scanning just like command "top", thanks first:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The utility watch is meant for this purpose also:

```
watch ps 4815
```

Answer (score 5):

If the process you want to see is PID *4815* and you want it to update every 2 seconds you could do an infinite while loop.

```
while true; do ps 4815; sleep 2; clear; done
```